# Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta POST com jquery no meu website online mas recebo a mensagem de erro 500 Internal Server Error, esta e a consulta (jquery):

`$('#background').load('map_page.php', {'a':'see_member', 'id': id});`

O bloco que recebe essa consulta na pagina map_page.php (php):

```
if($a == 'see_member') {
    $id = @$_POST['id'];
    if($id) {
        $q = $dbAgent -> query("select * from map where id=$id");
        $a = $dbAgent -> fetch($q);
        $logo = $a['logo'];
        $title = $a['name'];
        $desc = $a['description'];
        $address = $a['address'];
        echo "
            <a href='#' onclick='closeCompany($id)'>
                <img src='media/cancel.png' id='close'>
            </a>
            <img src='$logo' id='prof'>
        ";

        $r1 = $a['rate_1']; $r2 = $a['rate_2'];
        $r3 = $a['rate_3']; $r4 = $a['rate_4'];
        $r5 = $a['rate_5'];
        $allStars = array(
            0=>0, 1=>$r1, 2=>$r2, 3=>$r3,
            4=>$r4, 5=>$r5
        );
        $biggestStar = 0;
        for($i=1;$i<count($allStars);$i++) {
            $st = $allStars[$i];
            if($st > $allStars[$biggestStar]) {
                $biggestStar = $i;
            }
        }
        $NUM_STARS = 5;
        if(!$clientTools -> rated($id)) {
            echo "<span class='rate_stars' id='rate_stars' onmouseenter='setVoteAble($NUM_STARS,$id)'
                >";
        }
        else {
            echo "<span class='rate_stars' id='rate_stars'>";
        }
        for($i=1;$i<count($allStars);$i++) {
            if(($allStars[$i] < $allStars[$biggestStar] and $i < $biggestStar) or $i == $biggestStar) {
                echo "<img class='rate_star' id='rate_star_$i' src='/media/star_fill.gif'>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<img class='rate_star' id='rate_star_$i' src='/media/star_bg.gif'>";
            }
        }
        $numVotes = $allStars[$biggestStar];
        echo "<br><span id='numVotesStars'>$biggestStar estrelas. ($numVotes votos)</span>";
        echo "</span>";

        echo "
            <div class='p_map'>
            </div>
        ";

        echo "
            <div id='cont'>
                <center><text id='header'>$title</text></center>
                <br><br>
                <text id='content'>$desc</text>
                <br><br>
                <text id='content' style='font-weight: bold'>$address</text>
            </div>
        ";
        return;
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/A72pypih

Comment: Coloque esse código no início do seu arquivo php para verificar o erro e consulte pela URL do seu navegador, depois edite sua pergunta com overro: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Nada diferente, so pra lembrar a pagina carrega normalmente a parte, so com a consulta acontece isso.

Comment: Acesse a url direto no navegador map_page.php?[PARAMETROS] e veja o erro que será mostrado. Poste o erro caso não consiga identificar o problema..

Comment: @JuniorCT quando tiver trechos de códigos pra mostrar, não use links externos como o pastebin, mas poste aqui o código para que a pergunta não seja invalidada caso o link se perca.

Comment: Em qual linha está o erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mensagem "500 Internal Server Error" normalmente indica erro provindo do servidor web. Geralmente do Apache.

Uma causa comum é algum erro no htaccess.

Para apurar o erro, leia o log de erros do servidor.

Vale lembrar que esse tipo de erro não é acessível pelo PHP, por isso não conseguirá ler os detalhes do log ativando a exibição dos erros no PHP.

Contudo, nem sempre o erro é do webserver, pois é possível configurar o ambiente para que erros do PHP ou outro módulo, por exemplo, sejam tratados pelo webserver com o status 500.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, se esse código no pastbin for seu código completo, esta faltando as tags de abertura e fechamento do PHP. `<?php ?>` e existe um `return;` fora de uma função. E logo na linha 3 a variável $a está sendo utilizada em uma comparação `if ($a == 'see_member'){}`  porém ela não esta instanciada.

Segundo, você só receberá os erros em seu programa se dizer ao PHP que gostaria de vê-los. Isso evita que o PHP exiba erros em um sistema em produção, gerando desconforto ao usuário e insegurança ao sistema. Para habilitar os erros adicione as linhas abaixo no topo de seu arquivo PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Adicionalmente, você pode habilitar os erros em todos os scripts PHP alterando o seu [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/configuration.file.php), para isso basta alterar a diretiva `display_errors` como mostrado abaixo:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

No seu código existe alguns problemas, que se me permitir, gostaria de alertá-lo.

- Nunca use o `@` para suprimir os erros, isso alem de ser uma pratica ruim deixa seu código mais lento.
- Não misture HTML e PHP, sei que você esta começando, mas é bom já começar certo. [Procure por MVC](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceito-de-mvc-e-sua-funcionalidade-usando-o-php/22324) ou algum padrão de projeto que remova o acoplamento entre a visão e seu controle.

Answer (score -4):

Cara. A melhor coisa que você tem a fazer é criar um a script para fazer logo dos erros. Assim você sempre saberá o que está acontecendo. Estude sobre as funções `set_error_handler, mkdir e fwrite` e sobre a classe `SplFileObject` .