# Como tornar o xampp servidor local para outras estações?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

Estou fazendo isso em um windows server 2016 porém fica retornando o erro 500 "Internal Server Error" quando digito o ip dele em outra máquina local

Comment: Relacionado: [Error 500 Internal Server Error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103282).

Answer (score 3):

Erro 500 significa que houve algum erro no processamento do script no lado *server*.

Vou supor que no servidor isso não ocorra, que o script roda normalmente. Então provavelmente o erro está ligado à permissões, ou de execução ou de pasta (de repente colocar everyone com permissão execução ou algo assim) Também estou presumindo que vc esteja usando um `.htaccess` básico e que ele também está com as permissões certas.

Também é complicado se o script usar algum include de alguma pasta que não esteja abaixo da raiz do site. Também conferir se o mysql está usando um usuário que tenha permissões corretas. Ah não esqueça de conferir se o firewall está com as devidas permissões também.

Só por acrescentar, se vc quiser que nas máquinas não se utilize o IP do servidor mas um "nome de domínio" pode editar o arquivo `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` e acrescentar :

```
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx       localhost
```

onde `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` é o IP do seu servidor. Mas cuidado porque pode dar problemas em aplicativos que chamam exatamente "localhost" mas pode trocar por outro termo como por exemplo "intranet", ou seja quando abrir o * * e digitar o endereço `http://intranet` ele vai estar abrindo na verdade a página do servidor `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Não tenho certeza que esteja com todas as permissões corretamente. Eu tentei habilitar o que consegui para AllowOverride All